# Can I setup Heroku on Amazon EC2?

Tags: virtualization, nginx

I was curious if it is possible to have a similar setup like Heroku but deployed on Amazon EC2. Does each "dynos" equals to a Virtual Machine? AMI is like a VM and hence, does this means a VM in a VM? Will the performance be slowed down? I was thinking of using Nginx+Gunicorn for my Django projects. How does the load balancing works in this case?

Maybe I understood the setup wrongly. Can anyone enlighten me? I'm thinking of setting up similar for projects that I have using subdomains.

I understand that nginx has load balancing, but how do the deployment architecture works?

Hope I'm clear in my explanation.

Cheers,
Mickey

Answer (score 1):

Hiroku runs on EC2, so yes, it's possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

With the newly open source cloudfoundry paas you can deploy a similar enviroment to that of heroku. Once you have it up and running you can deploy your app to the stack , you can add components like mysql or mongo from the command prompt. Using RightScale is probably the fastest way to get up and running http://rdd.me/4ae0leds